# Approval process optimization

Tags: configuration, approval-process, approval-step

Currently I have 2 approval processes on a custom object. I have 5 checkboxes which when true will be auto submitted for approval by a process builder.

Current situation:

Approval#1 is triggered when any one of the fields 1, 2, 3 and 4 is checked and record is saved or edited. This approval process is of 2 steps. 1st step is approved by manager and 2nd step is approved by director.

Approval #2 is triggered when field 5 is checked and record is saved or edited. This approval has only 1 step approved by both managers and directors.

Problem:
Since only 1 approval process can be running state, I face problem with the 2  processes.

Is there any better way I can configure the 2 approval processes?

Comment: Can you elaborate this line: Since only 1 approval process can be running state, I face problem with the 2 processes.

Comment: Sure. Suppose field 1 and field 5 in the above situation is checked, I get the error that only one approval can be in running state.

Comment: whats your requirement when field 1 and 5 are checked? which process it will follow

Comment: Thanks santanu. We have been missing  out on this condition hence running into this dilema of 2 approval processes. What woud the correct way to proceed?

Comment: You should ask business about the scenario first and then design the process

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Basically you are trying to run 2 approval processes in parallel. This still isn't possible using standard Salesforce approvals. There are some tools on the AppExchange that do it. They work around standard approvals, though, and have their own mechanism/datamodel. E.g. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008Y8xfEAC and https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMcp7UAD

Also Salesforce CPQ approvals can do this (even on custom objects).